# Error message when adding Calendar Event

Tags: calendar, iphone

When adding a New Event to Calendar on the iPhone6, I get an error message "Cannot Save Event - That event does not belong to that event store." How are events suppose to be added to the calendar?

Answer (score 1):

You provided very little information, like what account (iCloud, Google Calendar, etc.) you are trying to add an event to. I suggest signing out of that account in `Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars` and then signing in again.